# Using spring:eval inside hasRole

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm displaying certain properties from property file in a JSP like so:

```
<spring:eval expression="@propertyConfigurer.getProperty('myproperty')"/>
```

Now, I'd like to use the same property inside `<sec:authorize access="hasRole()/>`

```
<sec:authorize access="hasRole('<spring:eval expression="@propertyConfigurer.getProperty('myproperty')"/>')">
```

which doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried this: <sec:authorize access="hasRole(@propertyConfigurer.getProperty('myproperty'))"> ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<spring:eval expression="@propertyConfigurer.getProperty('myproperty')" var="myproperty"/>
<sec:authorize access="hasRole('${myproperty}')">
```

Comment: Any idea how to use `${myproperty}` on some basic html tag? Eg:
`<script src="${myproperty}"/> is not working.

Comment: Figured it out. Here is the [jsp](http://pastebin.com/wCGPdMx3) and [here](http://pastebin.com/Bb4UbzMV) is the java class to load the property file.