# Using spring:eval display property value in jsp

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am looking for help to display the Spring property value in a jsp file.

I found one link which is having the same requirement of mine. 
Click [Using spring:eval inside hasRole](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15115356/using-springeval-inside-hasrole)

I am using **Spring 2.5**

This is my applicationContext-util.xml file:

```
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.5.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd

<util:properties id="viewPropertyConfigurer" location="classpath:conf/app_config.properties"/>
<context:property-placeholder properties-ref="viewPropertyConfigurer" />
```

in my menu.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<spring:eval expression="@viewPropertyConfigurer.getProperty('role.admin')" />
```

in lib folder I also have spring-web-2.5.6.jar file to make sure the eval should work fine in jsp. But not sure what is the issue once i add spring:eval tag the jsp is not at all loading it throws

```
[ERROR,context.JspTilesRequestContext,http-8080-1] -[UID=galips - SessionID=691A896E807850568DF9B0F5356F6CB2] - JSPException while including path '/WEB-INF/jsp/menu.jsp'.
```

In my application I am using servlet filter as well hope it will not be an issue.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Please share configuration file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know `EvalTag` was added in Spring 3 (`@since 3.0.1`). If you are using Spring 2.5, then you don't have `<spring:eval>` support.

Possible solutions:

- switch to Spring 3+
- use a custom handler interceptor to add additional information to your request
- write your own tag to pull up information from application context

---

Update (option 2 example):

```
public class CommonViewAttributesInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    private static final String PROPERTIES_ATTR = "properties";

    private Properties properties = new Properties();

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
        request.setAttribute(PROPERTIES_ATTR, properties);
    }

    public void setPropertiesSource(Resource resource) throws IOException {
        InputStream input = resource.getInputStream();
        try {
            properties.load(input);
        } finally {
            input.close();
        }
    }

}
```

Then you need to configure this interceptor within your handler mapping.

Comment: Thanks nidhin, Pavel Horal for your valuable information. I created the sample project with Spring **3+** and it is working fine. My project is in 2.5+ and now if I switch to 3.0 then it needs to change some packages and need to test the entire application.
Like Pavel Horal said creating the tag and get the property values
I can see there are 2 options to implement it.
i. Load the properties by java.
ii. Get the property values from Spring injected property file.

contd..

Comment: I want to go with 2nd option cuz I don't want to give file names in 2 places
I checked the PropertyResourceConfigurer api there is no way to get the value based on key. Is there anyway that I can get the values programatically
Please let me know if I am missing anything.

Comment: Sorry to bother you all. I got the link where how I can get the values from PropertyResourceConfigurer.
here is the 

[link to the code](http://codingbone.wordpress.com/2010/02/28/how-to-load-properties-files-into-spring-and-expose-to-the-java-classes/)

Comment: You can load properties twice - once for `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` and once within your custom handler interceptor. I've updated my answer with an example.

Comment: Hm... I've probably read your comments incorrectly. Are you going for the *custom tag* solution?

Comment: Yes, I created custom tag and it is working without any issue. Thanks again for your help.