# spring:eval a dynamic expression

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, eval

I have a variable:

<c:set var="evalExpression" value="figlio.getCustomfield1()==null?"": " - telefono:" + figlio.getCustomfield1()" />

how to make it evaluated by spring?

This does not work:

<spring:eval expression="${evalExpression}" />

Thanks!

Comment: similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16971565/using-springeval-display-property-value-in-jsp

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using spring:eval display property value in jsp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16971565/using-springeval-display-property-value-in-jsp)